# Understand Amazon S3 Bucket permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a bucket we want to store backups in.

The bucket is set to private not public (because it's backups) but when I try and give an IAM user permission to read and write to it AWS says that the bucket is private.

There is another bucket which is set to public where we're storing images and things that the any user should be able to see, but AWS complains that this one is set to public and is a security risk.

So not quite sure which setting should apply to which. The main goal at the moment is allowing restricted write access to the bucket for the purposes of backing up databases.

Any help would be greatly welcome :) thanks

Comment: Could you please share the IAM user permission you are using?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to keep the bucket private and give the permissions as needed, always using the Least Privilege Principle. In your case, you will need to give the users read and write permission with an IAM policy, such as the example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

For more information, you can check: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a go.

Comment: I am still getting "Granting public access in this policy will be blocked because Block public access settings are turned on for this bucket. To determine which settings are turned on, check your Block public access settings."
I notice that the above doesn't contain a principal - which I have set to the user.  This is the only difference I can see but the generator states: " You must enter one or more Principals."

Comment: @bldcaveman I believe you are refering to the Bucket Policy, is that correct? You should be adding IAM Policies to the IAM users authorized to access the bucket or create a group with the policy and add the users to the group. Please share your policy (removing sensitive data) so we can have details.

Comment: I think that was them just being overzealous because it works when in the order you put and with the star :)

Comment: @bldcaveman the /* refers to being able to put objects inside the bucket. If you don't have the /*, you are trying to implement permissions in the bucket level, not inside them.

Comment: @bldcaveman Just to clarify... This policy should go on the **IAM User**, NOT the Bucket Policy.